# Iterating through json data in django template

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm having trouble iterating through a JSON inside the django template.

My JOSN looks like,

```
{
"main_cats": [
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "BeeForms.maincategory",
        "fields": {
            "is_visible": true,
            "name": "Test Main",
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "base_category": 1,
            "help_text": "",
            "is_seller_field": false,
            "position": 10,
            "show_seller": true,
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    }
],
"sub_cats": [
    {
        "pk": 15,
        "model": "BeeForms.subcategory",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[0-9a-zA-Z]",
            "library_id": "TextBox",
            "input_length": 255,
            "name": "TextBox",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "field_type": "text",
            "main_category": 1,
            "is_active": true,
            "is_visible": true,
            "help_text": "",
            "position": 10,
            "is_required": true,
            "field_display_type": "input",
            "order_by_type": true,
            "has_enumerations": false
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 16,
        "model": "BeeForms.subcategory",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[A-Za-z0-9]",
            "library_id": "SelectBox",
            "input_length": 255,
            "name": "SelectBox",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "field_type": "",
            "main_category": 1,
            "is_active": true,
            "is_visible": true,
            "help_text": "",
            "position": 10,
            "is_required": false,
            "field_display_type": "select",
            "order_by_type": true,
            "has_enumerations": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 18,
        "model": "BeeForms.subcategory",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[0-9a-zA-Z]",
            "library_id": "TextArea",
            "input_length": 255,
            "name": "TextArea",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "field_type": "varchar",
            "main_category": 1,
            "is_active": true,
            "is_visible": true,
            "help_text": "",
            "position": 10,
            "is_required": false,
            "field_display_type": "textarea",
            "order_by_type": true,
            "has_enumerations": false
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 22,
        "model": "BeeForms.subcategory",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[A-Za-z0-9]",
            "library_id": "Checkbox",
            "input_length": 255,
            "name": "Checkbox",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "field_type": "",
            "main_category": 1,
            "is_active": true,
            "is_visible": true,
            "help_text": "",
            "position": 10,
            "is_required": false,
            "field_display_type": "checkbox",
            "order_by_type": true,
            "has_enumerations": true
        }
    }
],
"base_cats": [
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Sales Information",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 20,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Listing information",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 3,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 30,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Land & Tax",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 4,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 40,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Exterior Construction",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 5,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 50,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Interior/Utilities",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 6,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 60,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "HOA/Community",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 7,
        "model": "BeeForms.basecategory",
        "fields": {
            "form_type": 1,
            "position": 70,
            "order_by_asc": true,
            "name": "Remarks",
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    }
],
"enum_content": [
    {
        "pk": 58,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationcontent",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectYesA1",
            "name": "SelectYesA1",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "enum_type_category": 53,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 59,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationcontent",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectNoA1",
            "name": "SelectNoA1",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "enum_type_category": 53,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 60,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationcontent",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectCheckBoxYes",
            "name": "SelectCheckBoxYes",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "enum_type_category": 54,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 61,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationcontent",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectCheckBoxNo",
            "name": "SelectCheckBoxNo",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "enum_type_category": 54,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true
        }
    }
],
"enums": [
    {
        "pk": 20,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerations",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectYes",
            "name": "SelectYes",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "has_type": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true,
            "sub_category": 16
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 21,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerations",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "SelectNo",
            "name": "SelectNo",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "has_type": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true,
            "sub_category": 16
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 30,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerations",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "Yes",
            "name": "Yes",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "has_type": true,
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true,
            "sub_category": 22
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 31,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerations",
        "fields": {
            "library_id": "No",
            "name": "No",
            "order_by_asc": false,
            "is_visible": true,
            "has_type": false,
            "is_active": true,
            "position": 10,
            "order_by_type": true,
            "sub_category": 22
        }
    }
],
"enum_types": [
    {
        "pk": 53,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationtype",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[A-Za-z0-9]",
            "is_visible": true,
            "name": "SelectYesA",
            "library_id": "SelectYesA",
            "field_type": "",
            "is_active": true,
            "has_content": true,
            "enum_category": 20,
            "field_display_type": "select",
            "input_length": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 54,
        "model": "BeeForms.enumerationtype",
        "fields": {
            "regex": "[A-Za-z0-9]",
            "is_visible": true,
            "name": "",
            "library_id": "",
            "field_type": "",
            "is_active": true,
            "has_content": true,
            "enum_category": 21,
            "field_display_type": "checkbox",
            "input_length": 255
        }
    }
]
}
```

The code I use to create the json file is as follows.

```
    def serialize(self, instance_name, form, destination):
    """ Seralizes the information passed in."""

    # we need to make sure that the directory is real.
    if not os.path.exists(destination):
        os.makedirs(destination)

    # Lets grab all the information needed and serailize it all at the same time.
    base_cats = serializers.serialize('json', BaseCategory.objects.all().filter(form_type_id=form.id).order_by('id'))
    main_cats = serializers.serialize('json', MainCategory.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    sub_cats = serializers.serialize('json', SubCategory.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    enums = serializers.serialize('json', Enumerations.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    enum_types = serializers.serialize('json', EnumerationType.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    enum_content = serializers.serialize('json', EnumerationContent.objects.all().order_by('id'))

    # now that they are all serailized make it into a list of simplejson
    base_list = simplejson.loads(base_cats)
    main_list = simplejson.loads(main_cats)
    sub_list = simplejson.loads(sub_cats)
    enums_list = simplejson.loads(enums)
    enum_type_list = simplejson.loads(enum_types)
    enum_content_list = simplejson.loads(enum_content)

    # now we combine them all together...
    self.json_data = simplejson.dumps({'base_cats': base_list, 'main_cats': main_list, 'sub_cats': sub_list,
                                       'enums': enums_list, 'enum_types': enum_type_list,
                                       'enum_content': enum_content_list}, indent=4)

    print(self.json_data)

    # now that we combined them into json_data. Lets write it out to a file.
    with open(destination + instance_name + '.json', 'w') as json_write:
        json_write.write(self.json_data)
```

I load the JSON into a Python Object with the following.

```
with open(instance_location + '.json', 'r') as json_read:
        self.json_data = json_read.read()

# now lets take the data and load into json array
data = simplejson.loads(self.json_data)

# now lets grab each list.
base_cats = data['base_cats']
main_cats = data['main_cats']
sub_cats = data['sub_cats']
enums = data['enums']
enum_types = data['enum_types']
enum_content = data['enum_content']

# lets return it all!
return base_cats, main_cats, sub_cats, enums, enum_types, enum_content
```

In straight Python I'm able to loop through (for example base_cats) and get the information I need with the following for loop

```
for base in base_dict:
    print base['pk']
    print base['fields']['name']
```

When I try that for loop in the django template I get the error of:

> Could not parse the remainder: '['pk']' from 'base['pk']'

With how the JSON is structered how would I loop through it in the django template as the following is not working.

```
{% for base in base_cats %}
    {{ base['pk'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the fields with the dot operator in the template, not with brackets:

```
{% for base in base_cats %}
    {{ base.pk }}
{% endfor %}
```

For reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#template-variables

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @crzyone9584 If the answer solved your problem, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I understand that. I just finished reading the page that was linked and using it. Could you give me some time actually get back to mark something as an answer before telling me to mark it as an answer?

Comment: Lastly to fix the last issue of ['fields]'['name'] you just use base.fields.name

Comment: @crzyone9584 Yeah, you've got it. :)

Comment: @J.McBride thanks again for thelp! Really appreciated it. I was stuck on this all last night and a good chunk of this morning.